# how to make constant value in MSSQL without cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor

I have one table that I will loop without cursor in MSSQL.

```
Unit    Speed     C           Count         x      y
A     | 200     | 200       | 3           |   3  | 0
A     | 230     | 230       | 4           |   7  | 0
A     | 240     | 240       | 3           |  10  | 0
A     | 250     | 255       | 2           | >=12 | 5
A     | 260     | 255       | 2           |   2  | 0
A     | 270     | 255       | 2           |   4  | 0
A     | 280     | 255       | 3           |   7  | 0
A     | 290     | 255       | 4           |   11 | 0
A     | 300     | 260       | 2           | >=12 | 5
A     | 310     | 260       | 2           |   2  | 0
A     | 320     | 260       | 2           |   4  | 0
A     | 340     | 260       | 2           |   6  | 0
```

How to make **C** value is constant (speed + 5 for first record and C + 5  for next value) after summary of **X** value is equal or same with **12**?

I want to loop the record without cursor (because if I use cursor, database will be deadlocked).

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Absolutely unclear. Try to explain with desired output.

Comment: @MitchWheat, I think I got it. X is cumulative sum, when this sum is less 12 he wants 0 as Y then 5 when it is greater and reset.

Comment: yes.. i want the value of C was changed if sum of X less than 12. if sum of X less than 12 then C value is (speed+5) for new summary,,, and for next C value is (C + 5) if summary of X less than 12

Comment: and X value are sum of Count

Comment: Please have a look at the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30701067/revisions) to see how you could have formatted your table much more easily (by using 4 space indents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from common table expressions and some window functions I came up with the following solution. Note that you need some column to sort the table.

```
With cte AS 
(
SELECT RowOrder
      ,cCount
      ,SUM(cCount) OVER(order by RowOrder) As SumcCount

FROM Tbl
)

SELECT RowOrder
      ,cCount
      ,SumcCount % 12 as x
      ,CASE WHEN SumcCount >= 12 
       AND RANK() OVER (Partition by SumcCount / 12 ORDER BY RowOrder) = 1 THEN
           5
       ELSE
           0
       END As y   
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RowOrder
```

**Explanations:**

- [Common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) is a way to create temporary result sets.
- using the `SUM` function with the [`OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause allows for cumulative sums on cCount (i didn't want to use count since it's a reserved word).
- using the [`RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function gave me a simple way to determine if the cumulative sum of cCount equals to any multiplication of 12 or more. note that in the case there is also a condition that the cumulative sum of cCount is 12 or more.

Comment: i mean i want to set C value when sum of X less than 12. if sum of X still less than 12, then C value still constant even speed value are different. but based on your code, you were get the X value and Y value.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean. I've tested my suggestion using [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c66a/19) and it seems to do what you described in your question.